# More efficient way for this?

Tags: java, sum, factors

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to run this program?

It runs fine for lower numbers, but as you increase, so does the time - exponentially.  So a number like 1000000 takes forever

```
import java.util.*;

public class SumOfPrimes {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    long number = 0;

    System.out.println("This program outputs the sum of the primes of a given number.");
    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    number = in.nextLong();

    System.out.println("The sum of the primes below "+number+" is: "+sumOfPrimes(number));
}

public static long sumOfPrimes(long n){
    long currentNum = 2;
    long sum = 0;
    if (n > 2){
        sum = sum + 2;
    }

    while (currentNum <= n) {
        if (currentNum % 2 != 0 && isPrime(currentNum)) {
            sum = sum + currentNum;
        }
        currentNum++;
    }
return sum;
}

public static boolean isPrime(long currentNum){
    boolean primeNumber = true;

    for (long test = 2; test < currentNum; test++) {
        if ((currentNum % test) == 0){
            primeNumber = false;
        }
    }

return primeNumber;
}
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization and/or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: Why test numbers like 4,6,8... increment by two instead.

Comment: [Efficient Prime Number Generating Algorithms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Efficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are better prime-finding algorithms, but as a quick fix, you only need to test factors up through the square root of the current number, because if you find a factor above the square root, then you should have found a factor below the square root.

```
long stop = (long) Math.sqrt(currentNum);
for (long test = 2; test <= stop ; test++) {
```

Additionally, break out of the loop and return `false` if you have found a factor and thus proven the number composite.

If more efficiency is desired, you can implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) so that you only check possible factors that are themselves prime.

Comment: Very useful information, thank you! I forgot the sqrt thing.

Answer (score 1):

You really should store a set of prime numbers every time you find one, so you avoid dividing by all the numbers every time.

This thing: `currentNum % 2 != 0` could be written as `currentNum & 1`.

Also your algorithm is wrong, try giving 3 as input.

Comment: Did not know about the '&' sign, thank you.  And yea, I corrected the error, I had it using a remainder, when n just needed to be > 2.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: the & sign is a bitwise AND, so basically you will set all the bits to zero except the least significant. That one will be 0 or 1 depending on the currentNum, and if that bit is 0 then the number is even, otherwise is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Use Eratosthenes Sievie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes  You will find all primes below given number in O(n log n log n) and you will need to go once over whole table.

Answer (score 0):

i had written one.i can not make sure all is right.i have tested 1000000 in my machine,it just taken 31 ms.
the memory require:1000000*1bytes=1mb

```
public class FindPrime {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long begin=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(findPrime(1000000));

    System.out.println("cost time="+(System.currentTimeMillis()-begin)+"ms");

}

public static long findPrime(int max){
    boolean data[]=new boolean[max+1];
    long sum=0;
    int stop=(int) Math.sqrt(max);
    for(int i=2;i<=stop;i++){
        if(data[i]==false){
            sum+=i;

            int index=i+i;
            while(index<=max){
                data[index]=true;
                index=index+i;
            }
            //System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    stop=stop+1;

    for(;stop<=max;stop++){
        if(data[stop]==false){
            sum+=stop;
            //System.out.println(stop);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

}

Comment: you should use boolean type instead of int type.

Comment: require less memory,1000000*1byte=1mb